# Methods of disabling specific limbs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, d20-system

Are there any methods in official WotC sources of disabling specific limb or limbs on a living and/or non-living creature? Use Rope has obvious applications in conjunction with a grapple and pin, and has already been considered; I need to know about any other options, so please do not answer "Use Rope check".

Any other WotC officially approved options are what I'm looking for - a rules-as-written finding about specific limb disabling. For those not familiar with what is officially designated as first party content for 3.x, WotC has designated their own books, their website articles, the D&D cartoon DVD booklet, Dungeon magazine, Dragon magazine, and specific websites (Athas.org, Planewalker.com, Birthright.net, Spelljammer.org and the rest of the official sites - the content is co-owned and therefore first party) as the official first party content for the 3rd editions of D&D.

As all 3rd edition is also d20 system, any WotC produced or officially approved d20 sources are also valid sources for the answer.

It is possible that no such official rule exists, if so, then that will be the accepted answer.

Comment: While I know there aren't going to be many anyway, what kind of method would be best? You mention a skill check as a nonstarter, so would you prefer a feat, magic item, mundane item, spell, power, class feature, or something else? (I don't want folks to go through a million pages to find the game's ten different ways of immobilizing a limb when you're only interested in mundane items made of wood that cost less than 20 gp or something.)

Comment: If trying to perform amputations on foes in combat, see [this question.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87426/are-there-any-rules-for-sundering-natural-weapons)  If trying to slice a vampire's Achilles tendon, see [this question.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33401/8610) (Answers that focus on disabling any creature's limbs are probably what's desired, however.)

Answer (score 1):

## The game rarely allows disabling limbs

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* includes the Variant: Damage to Specific Areas (27). This would be the easiest way to include an effect like disabling a limb, but the results are rather tame: typically a minor penalty to specific skill checks that can even be overcome with a successful Fortitude saving throw.

The lasso (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 34) (1 gp; 3 lbs.), an exotic weapon, can be used to entangle a creature's arms, and [manacles](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/goodsAndServices.html#manacles-and-manacles-masterwork) (*PH* 126-7, 128) (15 gp; 2 lbs.) serve a similar purpose, the latter usable in combat by the prestige class justiciar (*Complete Warrior* 47-9), a fine class for those interested in restraints and [live-capture methods](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71034/8610).

Beyond that, the only thing I've found that specifically claims to disable limbs is the feat **Stone Monkey** (*Dragon* #309 46)—a feat pretty much exclusively for monks—, but its disabling effect only results in a −2 penalty on actions taken involving the limb and, possibly, a reduction in Speed. (The effect won't even work on, for example, an [iron golem](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89476/8610): disabling a limb using the benefit of the feat Stone Monkey requires the creature to fail a Fortitude saving throw, which the iron golem needn't even *make* against the effect because the effect doesn't *also* affect objects, no matter how hard the player tries to force it to (*Player:* "I Stone Monkey the table leg!" *DM:* "No and stop it").)